# deploying Axis2.war in tomcat 5.5 gets internal server error

Tags: apache, apache-axis, tomcat5.5

I have downloaded the axis2.war file from the apache website.

I put it in the tomcat/webapps folder and it automatically creates a axis2 folder.

I open my web browser and navigate to http://127.0.0.0:8080/axis2/ and get the page that has services, validate and administration.

The problem is that if I click on any of the links a page with the apache logo is shown saying internal server error.

I have tried extracting the axis2.war my self and the file list is the same. the official apache website says that the axis2.war may not have unpacked correctly or it could be missing files. i have tries 1.6 and 1.5 of axis2 and still get the same error.

Can anyone explain what is causing this error and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out that it was the security settings blocking AXIS2

Comment: You should add what security concerns that you had to fix. This will help people like me who are facing the same problem.

Comment: What security settings? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please copy jstl-1.2.jar file in the %CATALINA_HOME%\lib folder. It will definitely solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

did you check weather tomcat is running.http://127.0.0.0:8080/.

please go through the following link to setup and test axis properly.

http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-installingtesting.html

Comment: if it wasn't how would I get the first screen that has links to the server error ?

Answer (score 0):

copy jstl-1.2.jar file in the Tomcat-Home\lib Folder, then your Problem Will Solve.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem although i was not able to login on the axis2 administration on the localhost (http://localhost:8080/axis2/axis2-admin/) where i also got the "internal server error". After removing the old axis2 (axis2.1.7.5) and deploying an older version (axis2.1.7.0) it was possible for me to login with the default username and password (admin, axis2). It could be that the newer axis2 file was corrupted but i have not reinstalled the newer version yet.